# How to check oracle listner status by java program on linux Server

Tags: java, linux, oracle

How to check oracle listener status by java program on Linux Server.

How I do the server by manually.
After login to the server, I have to execute `.oraenv` proflie of oracle database 
which asks for `Oracle SID{Oracle database name}`
then it will start working

**lsnrctl status command.**

> [oracle@xx$ . oraenv
>   ORACLE_SID = [daltaasm] ? deltaasm
>   The Oracle base has been set to /u01/app/oracle
>   oracle@XX$ clear
>   oracle@xx$ . oraenv
>   ORACLE_SID = [deltaasm] ? deltaasm
>   The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /u01/app/oracle
>   oracle@xx$ ^C
>   oracle@xx$ lsnrctl status
>
> LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on 05-APR-2018 05:18:21
>
> Copyright (c) 1991, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
>
> ### STATUS of the LISTENER
>
> Alias                     LISTENER
>   Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
>   Start Date                02-APR-2018 11:45:50
>   Uptime                    2 days 17 hr. 32 min. 31 sec
>   Trace Level               off
>   Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
>   SNMP                      OFF
>   Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/deltaoramegan/listener/alert/log.xml
>   Listening Endpoints Summary...
>     (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=DeltaOraMegan.local)(PORT=1521)))
>   Services Summary...
>   Service "+ASM" has 1 instance(s).
>     Instance "+ASM", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
>   Service "deltaasm" has 1 instance(s).
>     Instance "deltaasm", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
>   Service "deltaasmXDB" has 1 instance(s).
>     Instance "deltaasm", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
>   The command completed successfully
>   oracle@xx$ ^C

So how to implement java program to check lsnrctl status command status

If I don't do manually execuation. oraenv profile on Linux server 
it will show lsnrctl status command not found

> ex oracle@xx$ snrctl status
>   lsnrctl status command not found

Please suggest the problem solution in java program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`oraenv` is just a wrapper shell script that will set `$ORACLE_HOME`, `$ORACLE_SID`, `$ORACLE_BASE` and the `$PATH` variable for you. You can just open it with a text editor and you will see all the shell code.
In a nutshell, it will look at `/etc/oratab` where Oracle records the information of Oracle homes (there can be more than one on a given server) and also which database uses those which Oracle home.

The `lsnrctl` binary can be found in `$ORACLE_HOME/bin`, so the trick is to find out what `$ORACLE_HOME` is. If you install it in a fixed location, you can just simple set the `$ORACLE_HOME` and `$PATH` accordingly, for example:

Assuming that I installed the Oracle software in `/opt/oracle/product/12.2.0.1/dbhome_1` my environment variables would look as follows:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/12.2.0.1/dbhome_1
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
```

From that point on you can now just call `lsnrctl` (because it's now in the `$PATH`).

So, the trick is to find out where you have the Oracle software installed which you can just find out by looking at `/etc/oratab` or, in case you always install it in the same place (very often the case), just set the variables beforehand.

Comment: Thank You  gvenzl,

Comment: How to export $ORACLE_HOME and $PATH in java program so oracle related commands will work.
   
   
   Suppose if I execute ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1  and export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin from terminal now if i  run Linux command lsnrclt status it gives result.
   
   So how I can do this using Java program so that will be on the path and i can get the result of lsnrctl status command result
   Can you suggest gvenzl
Please suggest this problem.

Comment: Hi @KailasKakade, your Java program will inherit the environment variables from the shell when started. So all you have to make sure is to have them set before you start your Java program. Alternatively, you can ask the user to pass it on, or you can read the `/etc/oratab` file.

Comment: I found another solution where I can only check the listener status just by executing Linux command. ps -ef|grep [l]snr

Comment: It's very hard to check lsnrctl status command by java program Especially whey you are loading env variables in the java program. I have tried using process builder as well as process class of java both solutions don't  work

Comment: Yup, if you can just execute a command on the shell it's certainly much, much easier. Happy to hear that you found a solution :)

Comment: Yes gvenzl , I agree with that.